# CSS image replacement working with images off and transparent images

Tags: css

I'm looking for a CSS image replacement technique (image replacement described for example [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-image-replacement-museum/)) — you hide element text contents and show image instead — which will work with transparent images and show the replaced text when images are turned off (for example by Windows High Contrast Mode).

I know techniques, which work with images having non-transparent background, but they stop to work when the image has non-transparent background — the element's text is visible through the background.

One example of such a technique below - setting the desired background on absolutely positioned pseudo child, which renders over the element. The issue: the text which I want to hide is still visible.

Illustrated in [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOwbyp).

## HTML

```
<div>Text which I want to replace by an image</div>
```

## CSS

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Perspective-Button-Go-icon.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Other techniques hide the text even with transparent image, but then not show the text when images are disabled, which is something I need. I'm looking for a one that does both.

Comment: Please use punctuation more. It's hard to read/understand.

Comment: @ProEvilz Is it clearer now? Actually it's a little hard to describe using words only.

Comment: why don't you just use background-color on your :after to hide the text?

Comment: Can you use the <img> element and set the alt text?

Comment: @DD84 I don't want to, because that's a decoration image that shouldn't be inside the content, so that to make the document more accessible.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez Haha, you're right, of course I should! I guess I'd convinced myself that the problem was so hard that I failed to see the simplest of answers. You should put that as an answer and I'll accept it, cause it's simpler and more flexible solution than the only answer, which has been given so far.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez I was too quick to evaluate your solution. As Scoots correctly pointed out, your solution won't work with the images turned off, because the background color will still stay.

Comment: No problem mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a known opaque image over the top with a lower z-index than the replacement image, like a 1px x 1px white png.

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

div::before,
div::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div::before {
    background-image: url('/images/white-pixel.png');
    z-index: 1;
}

div::after {
    background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Perspective-Button-Go-icon.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

You could take this a step further and actually base-64 encode the image and embed it directly into the stylesheet:

```
div::before {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCA‌​QAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQV‌​R42mP8/x8AAwMCAO+ip1‌​sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: It's a proper solution, only Alvaro Menéndez provided a similar but simpler one, so I'll wait for him to post it and accept it as an answer. Still thanks.

Comment: @Robert You mentioned in your question that you want the text to show up when images are disabled - make sure background colours get disabled at the same time in the browsers you need to support before implementing that solution

Comment: You're right - his solution won't work with the images disabled. Then I'm accepting your answer. Shame it's not possible with CSS only, without creating any additional images :/.

Comment: @Robert Well... You might be able to get a middle ground here. One thing you can do in CSS is base64 an image and use that as your background. This rule will set a white 1x1 pixel image as a background, but I don't know how it will behave under the conditions you describe. `background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP8/x8AAwMCAO+ip1sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);`

Comment: @Scotts That's a good idea. I'll try it and report the results here.

Comment: Not only it does work, but I also wrote a Sass encoding function to automate the process — you provide a color and it returns base64 encoded SVG image of that solid color, which you can use as a background. That's perfect solution, which I feel will work for me for years to come. Thanks for getting me on the right path! BTW I think you should include a note about Base64 image in your answer, as that makes it a cleaner CSS-only solution.

Comment: @Robert Good shout, have done. A SASS mixin to auto build the image in any colour - could I persuade you to share that code? Sounds both pretty cool and potentially pretty useful.

Comment: Sure, I'll gladly share it: https://pastebin.com/ecsHRmet. The main Sass mixin is `image-replacement`, other are just helpers. The mixin got pretty complicated, but mostly because I wanted it to be flexible and reusable; the whole guts is the logic inside `inline-svg-solid-color` mixin. And as `inline-svg-solid-color` mixin uses `base64Encode` function (not available in Sass natively), I needed to add that function to `node-sass` (documentation on how to do it here: https://github.com/sass/node-sass#functions--v300---experimental).